# Can't pass variable to GraphQL?

Tags: flutter, dart, graphql

Why I get this error?

```
Undefined name 'id'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name
```

Here the code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:graphql_flutter/graphql_flutter.dart';
import 'package:xxx/tenancy_list_response.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

abstract class TenancyRemoteData {
  Future<List<TenancyListResponse>?> getTenancyList();
}

class TenancyRemoteDataSource implements TenancyRemoteData {
  TenancyRemoteDataSource(this._client);

  final GraphQLClient _client;

  @override
  Future<List<TenancyListResponse>?> getTenancyList() async {
    try {
      final result = await _client.query(QueryOptions(document: gql('''
 query getTenancyListQuery($id:Int!) {    // here the error
    tenancy(tenant_id_eq: $id){   // here the error
    id
  }
}
'''), variables: {'id': 6}));

      return result.data?['tenancy']
          .map((e) => TenancyListResponse.fromJson(e))
          .cast<TenancyListResponse>()
          .toList();
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint("Exception $e");
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are using `$` in a string which evaluates the expression you put after. In your case it is `id`, so it tries to look for the variable `id`.

**Solution 1: Use raw string:**

Add `r` in front of `'''`:

```dart
r'''
 query getTenancyListQuery($id:Int!) {
    tenancy(tenant_id_eq: $id){
    id
  }
}
'''
```

---

**Solution 2: Escape `$`:**

Add `\` in front of `$`:

```dart
'''
 query getTenancyListQuery(\$id:Int!) {
    tenancy(tenant_id_eq: \$id){
    id
  }
}
'''
```

Comment: thanks,error gone after I add ' in front, but I not getting any data..it is empty.

Comment: I have edited my post..is it because id is null?

Comment: What do you mean you are not getting any data? From your backend?

Comment: ya..backend return empty data

Comment: post edited again

Comment: I think this is another issue. This might be an issue with your setup, your token etc. Which is different from your initial question which was about dart's strings

Comment: hmmm..but if hardcoded it in code, it worked..